# How to fix "Run-time error' 13' Type mismatch when opening a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open two separate workbooks via VBA in Excel and, somehow, the same code lines work in one case, but do not in the second one.

My first code line works properly:

```
Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(path & fName & fExt, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)
```

The second one, however, do not, it does open the file, but do not store it as wb2 and returns a Mistype error.

```
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(path1 & fName1 & fExt1,UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)
```

[EDIT] This is the whole code set:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update_Supply_Concerns()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim wb, WB1, WB2 As Workbooks
    Dim ws, ws1, ws2 As Worksheets
    Dim path, path1, path2 As String
    Dim fName, fName1, fName2 As String
    Dim uName As String
    Dim rDate As String
    Dim fExt, fExt1 As String

    uName = Environ$("username")

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Macro")

    With ws
        .Activate

        rDate = .Range("D6").Value

        path = "C:\Users\" & uName & "\Documents\Projects\" & rDate & "\"
        fName = "Hospital"
        fExt = ".xlsx"
        path1 = "C:\Users\" & uName & "\Box Sync\Supply Concerns 2.0\"
        fName1 = "Supply Concerns v2"
        fExt1 = ".xlsx"

        Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(path & fName & fExt, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)
        Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(path1 & fName1 & fExt1, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)
    End With
End Sub
```

I've tried activating the parent workbook before attempting to open the second file, with no success.

```
Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(path & fName & fExt, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)
        wb.Activate
        Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(path1 & fName1 & fExt1, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. The code fragments that you provide involve all sorts of variables (such as `wb`) whose declarations and initializations are elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, John. I've added the whole code set in the original question. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem is that

```
Dim wb, WB1, WB2 As Workbooks
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It declares `wb, WB1` as simple Variants and then declares `WB2` as a Workbooks (note the "s"!) object. It doesn't declare any of those three variables as a *Workbook* object.

Since `WB1` is a variant (which can hold a workbook object) the line

```
Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(path & fName & fExt, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)
```

is unproblematic. But since `WB2` is declared to be a *workbooks* object, the line

```
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(path1 & fName1 & fExt1,UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)
```

is a type mismatch since you are trying to use a workbooks variable to hold a workbook object.

To start fixing your code, use the declaration:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, WB1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook
```

(and fix some of your other declarations as well).

Comment: Thanks John. That was it.

Comment: @JoseGonzález Glad I could help. If it solved your problem, consider marking the answer as "accepted".